# Laravel overrid parent views in packages

Tags: laravel, view

I have a project in larval 8 and each time there is an update I need to do change of views one by one.So for that I need to create a custom package that overrides the parent views without changing in the parent project.

so my question is how to add location to the paths in the view.php config, i tried this code in my provider but without success:

```
       $this->app['view.finder']->addLocation('my_path');
        dd($this->app['view.finder']);
```

the paths is unchanged ?

Answer (score 0):

ok this is how:

```
 View::getFinder()->prependLocation(dirname(__DIR__) . '/resources/views/my package/views');
```